# "guess on" vs. "guess about"

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to figure out when should I use "guess on" and "guess about".

I've gone through [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/guess) but got nothing about that.

Inspired by [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guess%20on%2C%20guess%20about&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cguess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bguess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGuess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguess%20about%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cguess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bguess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGuess%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguess%20about%3B%2Cc0), I make up the following contexts.

## context 1

In a classroom, the teacher asks the students to answer a math question while nobody really knows the answer.

> teacher: just give me a guess
>
> student: my **guess on** that question is ...

## context 2

A and B are talking about the housing prices

> A: what's your guess **about** the housing prices next year?
>
> B: because of the pandemic, the housing prices will drop a lot.

In context 1, the preposition is used "on" as the answer is known while the answer is unknown in context 2.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As far as I know, guess on or guess about are not a phrase verb. On and guess are just preposition for the verb guess. Therefore, they can be the same thing.

Comment: I don't think there's any rule. You can guess on, of, about, concerning, regarding...

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. So, you are saying I can use those prepositions interchangeably for any cases, right?

Comment: I can't think of any examples that would definitely be wrong.